# Xamarin form how to test iOS 12.1.3

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios12

I can see emulator for iOS 12.1 in Xamarin but can’t see the one with iOS 12.1.3.

Do i need to install anything

Comment: Did you update the xcode?

Comment: there was no update when going to app store.

Comment: I went to xCode in preference -> components -> simulator 12.0 simulator is the latest i can find in the list. Inside xamarin, under simulator i can should either OS 12.1 or OS 12.0

Comment: The latest version of emulator in `XCode` is `iOS 12.1` right now. Seems Apple haven't update the emulator. You can use a real device with system 12.1.3 instead.

Comment: haven;t have the iphone device to check that ...